# Access a running MATLAB instance from command line

Tags: ssh, vnc, matlab

I am running a few instances of MATLAB on a server via an SSH tunnel and a VNC server. I started the instances using the desktop (via VNC) but something went wrong and now the desktop is completely unresponsive.

The instances are still running (I checked this by running `top`) but I can't view them using VNC (for the aforementioned reason). I know it's possible to run MATLAB directly from the command line (which I did not do), but is it possible to somehow access the already running MATLAB instances from the command line, circumventing the VNC server?

---

**Update**: It appears that if I wait a while (at least a few hours), the desktop will respond for about 5 seconds before locking up again.